# windows driver development: context switch callback?

Tags: windows, kernel, context-switch

Is it possible for a driver to register a callback in the kernel for every context switch?

thanks!

Comment: What would you use this for? Just curious.

Comment: Performance counters which track a specific process need to be notified of context switch in/out.

Answer (score 1):

No. Context switches happen too frequently. There are APIs to register yourself for notification of thread / process creation / termination (PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutine, etc). Maybe that would help?